# Хоть один рабочий способ отправки на smtp

Tags: c#, smtp

Через стандартный SmtpClient не могу отравить сообщение ни с какого ящика ни на какой. Мэил, яндекс, гмаил, раком, все перепробовал, но везде под разными предлогами вылетает ошибка. И `client.EnableSsl = true;` я включал, и 25 порт ставил, чего только не пробовал. Как выйти из ситуации? Какой ящик использовать и с какими настройками надо использовать, чтобы наконец заработало?

Делал примерно так -

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("x2zn****@yandex.ru"); 
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("s*****@mail.ru")); 
        mail.Subject = "Заголовок";
        mail.Body = "Письмо........................";

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Host = "smtp.yandex.ru";
        client.Port = 587; 

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("x2zn****@yandex.ru", "*******");
        client.Send(mail);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Для отправки письма никакой "ящик" не нужен. Нужна только smtp аутентификация и знание - через какой порт отправлять, и вот это почитайте https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server там речь про порт и ограничения.

Comment: Для начала - покажите код, которым вы пробовали отправить почту. Обычно там все достаточно триваиально - нужно просто всписать в код настройки от конкретного провайдера.

Comment: @PashaPash добавил.

Comment: @Stepan ок. осталось вписать туда настройки из https://yandex.ru/support/mail/mail-clients.html - "порт — 465."

Comment: Не знаю, как у топикстартера, а у меня код (с изменением порта на 465) работает. Закрываем как опечатку... "все перепробовал"... кроме чтения документации.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/21.1.php Вот рабочий способ. Сам проверял.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит ещё от самого SMTP сервера, так как иногда исключение может не возникать но статус код будет к примеру 221 <домен>Служба закрывает канал передачи (У меня было так, поменял SMTP с прошлого на Gmail и всё заработало)

часто у них есть кучи параметров которые должен реализовывать в себе сам сервер

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // отправитель - устанавливаем адрес и отображаемое в письме имя
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("test*****@yandex.ru", "Igor");
        // кому отправляем
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("*******@yandex.ru");
        // создаем объект сообщения
        MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);
        // тема письма
        m.Subject = "Тест1";
        // текст письма
        m.Body = "Тест";
        // письмо представляет код html
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
        // адрес smtp-сервера и порт, с которого будем отправлять письмо
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.ru", 25);
        // логин и пароль
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test******@yandex.ru", "*********");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(m);
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Только что проверил. Все отправляет. Так же нужно добавить пространство имен
        using System.Net.Mail;
        using System.Net;

Comment: Среди проблем топикстартера, которые относятся к программированию находятся и те, которые относятся к уровню администрирования. Некоторые (читай: многие) провайдеры ещё лет пять назад массово блокировали ИСХОДЯЩИЙ трафик по 25 порту с домашнего интернета, так как народ массово хватал троянов. В общем-то эта практика и до сих пор много где сохранилась, да кто ж читает мелкий шрифт в договоре/на сайте? Поэтому открывали порт 2525 (дважды по 25 - легко запомнить), это у вас работает 25 порт, а у меня вот - нет. И с переходом на TLS порты могут быть другие.

Comment: Поэтому пишем код, читаем документацию конкретной почтовой службы и смотрим настройки конкретного интернет-провайдера.

Comment: Сервер исходящей почты (SMTP): 
Адрес сервера: smtp.yandex.ru
Использовать аутентификацию: Да
Порт с шифрованием: 465
Порт без шифрования: 25, 587